# Hide App name in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I need some guide to remove the name of app which is quite annoying in top bar of navigation: [App Top Bar Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8cdF.jpg)

I'm using `Toolbar` and native google Navigation Drawer I tried some method like:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

but **application** stop working

or **changing** theme but not working

Comment: you are using ActionBarActivity or AppCompatActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must first call this `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);`
also make sure that you are using style with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`